Task Manager for Linux
I'm looking for a tool similar to Windows Task Manager or Gnome System Monitor that makes it easier to manage running applications.
The main issue: Many applications consist of multiple processes, but Gnome System Monitor etc only provides a list of processes.
There is no way to see the memory/CPU/disk/network usage of big applications like Firefox because you'd have to find all the processes belonging to it and add their numbers together. Even if I filter for "firefox", I'm completely overwhelmed by results:

I'm looking for a tool that could give a me a more useful list of running applications and their total impact on memory, CPU, disk io and network io.
Gnome System Monitor in tree mode, is also not very useful:

Windows Task Manager is certainly not perfect, but imo it is doing a much better job at this:

Unfortunately I can't find a Linux equivalent.

Did you try procexp? It's a GUI that tries to be an alternative to Windows Process Explorer, which is the best process manager in my opinion.
It lists processes in a reasonable tree:

